# Electron application shows an extra border on transparent mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

My Electron application is in transparent mode and is showing an extra border on window.

See the image below and my code.

[image]

My code to create the window.

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
title: 'WeDraw',
autoHideMenuBar: true,
transparent: true,
frame: false,
titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true
}
```

});

Comment: Is that on macOS? You sure you don't simply have another window behind it? ;)

Comment: Yes. I'm using MacOS Catalina. No, I haven't another window behind.